# Writing to delta table fails with "not enough data columns"?

Tags: databricks, delta-lake

I was trying to execute below spark-sql code in data bricks which is doing Insert Overwriting on other table. which are have same no.of columns with same names.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE cs_br_prov
  SELECT NAMED_STRUCT('IND_ID',stg.IND_ID,'CUST_NBR',stg.CUST_NBR,'SRC_ID',stg.SRC_ID,
  'SRC_SYS_CD',stg.SRC_SYS_CD,'OUTBOUND_ID',stg.OUTBOUND_ID,'OPP_ID',stg.OPP_ID, 
  'CAMPAIGN_CD',stg.CAMPAIGN_CD,'TREAT_KEY',stg.TREAT_KEY,'PROV_KEY',stg.PROV_KEY, 
  'INSERTDATE',stg.INSERTDATE,'UPDATEDATE',stg.UPDATEDATE,'CONTACT_KEY',stg.CONTACT_KEY) AS key,
  stg.MEM_KEY,
  stg.INDV_ID,
  stg.MBR_ID,
  stg.OPP_DT,
  stg.SEG_ID,
  stg.MODA,
  stg.E_KEY, 
  stg.TREAT_RUNDATETIME
  FROM cs_br_prov_stg stg
```

Error which i am getting was :

```
AnalysisException: Cannot write to 'delta.`path`', not enough data columns;
target table has 20 column(s) but the inserted data has 9 column(s)
```

Comment: What DBR version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is as the exception says, the `SELECT` subquery creates a logical plan with just 9 columns (not 20 as the `cs_br_prov` table expects).

Unless the table uses generated columns, the exception is perfectly fine.